# Database with list of generic ingredients and their nutrients?

Tags: data-request

I need a dataset with generic ingredients and their nutrition. I am familiar with USDA and other similar ingredients datasets but they are all polluted with a lot of brands and very long descriptions.

For example, if my user searched "egg" I want it to return just the ingredient object and the nutritional facts.

Using the USDA datasets I would find around 10 types of eggs... I am looking for something more simple or generic.

Comment: eggs come in different sizes...